# jQuery 'Undefined' error on basic show/hide code

Tags: jquery, undefined

I have some pretty simple code:

```
var overlay = {
    show: function() {
        var width = $('#checkout-region').outerWidth();
        var height = $('#checkout-region').outerHeight();
        // Set vars and show
        $('#checkout-processing').css({
            'height': height + 'px',
            'width': width + 'px'
        }).fadeIn(300);
    },
    hide: function() {
        $('#checkout-processing').fadeOut(300);
    }
}
```

To just allow me to overlay.show(); and overlay.hide();. When I try to run them in the console (Chrome) I continue to get a (very useful) 'undefined'. A simple console.log('ok'); shows the functions are there but I just can't figure this one out.

It's probably something stupid but I'm sleep deprived and have been working on this project way too long now. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you *expect* the output to be? The functions do not return a value, hence `undefined`.

Comment: The expected result is that the overlay (abs-positioned object) shows over the content.

Comment: Look for undefined variables in your code. `process_overlay` is undefined for example.

Comment: I've updated the code with a direct reference (I was using variable references), still no luck.

Comment: Perhaps try debugging. Step through the methods, and verify that the values of `width` and `height` are correct. Additionally, note that the `undefined` result displayed is not an error at all.

Comment: @Fluidbyte do you still get the error? I can run this code even on this page and not get any errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Undefined` is not an error, it's a return value.

Those functions return Undefined because they have no `return something;` line.

if you are trying to debug your code, you should console.log your query results to see if your queries are returning the correct elements. like so:

```
console.log($('#checkout-processing'));
```

if this works, the element should be fading out.